# Python-Multiple header on dataframe

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, export, target

I have a dataframe which I export to excel file:

```
import pandas as pd    
Archivo_Descargado =r'C:\Users\Downloads\\'
FD_File="Prueba.xlsx" 
FD_Descarga= pd.read_excel(f'{Archivo_Descargado}{FD_File}')
full_path = f'{Archivo_Descargado}Aging.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(full_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
FD_Descarga.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Aging', index=False)
workbook = writer.book
writer.save()
```

Example data:

| Collector | % 0-3 days | %4-10 days | %11-20 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Juan | 60 | 25 | 15 |
| Maria | 55 | 25 | 20 |

But I need to add a 2nd header and export to excel, called target above the first header

|  Target    |     70%        |      30%    |   0%       |

| Collector | % 0-3 days | %4-10 days | %11-20 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Juan | 60 | 25 | 15 |
| Maria | 55 | 25 | 20 |

Any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A not elegant approach would be to add this to the top:

```
import openpyxl
```

and add the following after your code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(full_path)
ws = wb['Aging']
ws.insert_rows(1)
ws['A1'] = 'Target'
ws['B1'] = '70%'
ws['C1'] = '30%'
ws['D1'] = '0%'
wb.save(full_path)
```

This is just inserting the line after the fact. I'm sure someone more savvy will have a better solution. It sounds like the additional row is unrelated to your DateFrame, so there is something to be said for applying a header after the fact.

| Target | 70% | 30% | 0% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Collector | % 0-3 days | %4-10 days | %11-20 days |
| Juan | 60 | 25 | 15 |
| Maria | 55 | 25 | 20 |

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your help, one quick question how to specify which worksheet it's adding the change?

Comment: The line ws=wb[‘Aging’] is choosing the worksheet by name.